# Rolling Sum on 3 months on pandas pivot table columns

Tags: pandas, pivot

I'm trying to calculate the rolling sum of values ​​on columns with a 3 month period on this pivot table. I would like to add a column to count how many times the rolling sum has exceeded 1.0 on each row.
Could you guide me please?

Thank you in advance for your help !

```
    dict_multi_index={'Country': {0: 'Austria',
    1: 'Austria',
    2: 'Austria',
    3: 'Austria',
    4: 'Austria'},
    'Site': {0: 'Site1',
    1: 'Site2',
    2: 'Site2',
    3: 'Site2',
    4: 'Site2'},
    'Name': {0: 'X',
    1: 'R',
    2: 'R',
    3: 'R',
    4: 'R'},
    'MODE': {0: 'pineapple',
    1: 'apple',
    2: 'banana',
    3: 'potatoe',
    4: 'watermelon'},
    '2020-11': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2020-12': {0: 1.0, 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: 1.0},
    '2021-01': {0: 1.0, 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-02': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0},
    '2021-03': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-04': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-05': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-06': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-07': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-08': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-09': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-10': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-11': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2021-12': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2022-01': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2022-02': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
    '2022-03': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0'}}

    pivot_table=pd.DataFrame(dict_multi_index)
    print(pivot_table)
```

Comment: if I understand correctly you need the amount of 1.0 in the matrix? then `pivot_table=pivot_table.set_index(["Country","Site","Name","MODE"])` `(pivot_table == 1.0).sum(axis="columns")` this should do the job

Comment: Thank you for your answer !Not exactly, I would only like to count the number of times when values ​​greater than 0 are consecutive over a sliding window of 3 months. Hard to explain ^^

Comment: but thats just a small change to the query above, you just need to change the condition to > 0 then.